# Error 404 Spring boot ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

Fala Galera, estou tentando criar uma aplicação RESTful com spring boot aqui no ubuntu, porém, quando executo a aplicação "Run as java application", o servidor sobe mas me parece que nao faz o deploy da aplicação, pois quando tento acessar a url dá erro 404.

**Detalhe:
No windows funciona.**

Única classe:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  String home() {
    return "Hello World!";
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  } 
}
```

POM.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

AQUI ESTÁ O LOG

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-02-07 21:13:27.814  INFO 3975 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on meu pc
2017-02-07 21:13:27.817  INFO 3975 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-02-07 21:13:27.858  INFO 3975 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64cd705f: startup date [Tue Feb 07 21:13:27 BRST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-07 21:13:28.894  INFO 3975 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-02-07 21:13:28.904  INFO 3975 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-02-07 21:13:28.905  INFO 3975 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-02-07 21:13:28.974  INFO 3975 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-02-07 21:13:28.975  INFO 3975 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1119 ms
2017-02-07 21:13:29.011  INFO 3975 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-02-07 21:13:29.226  INFO 3975 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-02-07 21:13:29.256  INFO 3975 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-02-07 21:13:29.262  INFO 3975 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 1.881 seconds (JVM running for 2.131)
```

Url's que tentei acessar: 
localhost:8080 
localhost:8080/demo 
localhost:8080/demo/DemoApplication

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tenta alterar a porta.

Comment: Fala Lucas blza? obrigado pelo feedback, eu alterei a porta aqui e o erro ainda persiste :(

Comment: É estranho porque ele não sinaliza nenhum tipo de erro. O log está completo ou é só uma parte?

Comment: Sim, não  sinaliza nada, esse é o log completo :(, e o mais estranho é que no windows funciona...

Comment: Tente acessar com o IP da sua máquina ao invés de utilizar o localhost.

Comment: tentei agora e sem sucesso. :(, eu procurei na net e também não achei a solução pra isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53217/discussion-between-lucas-kauer-and-higor-senna).

Comment: Qual navegador você está utilizando?

Comment: testei no chrome e no firefox

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você não tenha permissão no seu diretório. Caso não tenha, tente executar o seguinte comando:

`sudo chmod +x "seu diretorio"`

**Atualizado**
Tente também acessar da seguinte forma no Firefox:

`0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: Executei os dois passos, e sem sucesso :(

Answer (score 0):

Poderia tentar forçar o Spring a escanear a classe:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = DemoApplication.class)
```

Outra coisa, a anotação *@SpringBootApplication* está em alguma outra classe da aplicação? Acredito que ela deveria estar na  DemoApplication.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo feedback, então, essa aplicação é apenas para teste e possui apenas esta classe DemoApplication, vou testar da forma que você falou.

Comment: Testei aqui, e sem sucesso :(

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei um projeto utilizando este pom e funcionou:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>teste</groupId>
  <artifactId>teste</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

<name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

`<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>   
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`

A única diferença é que utilizei a versão 1.4.0 do spring-boot-starter-parent.

Outro detalhe, no pom que você colocou eu não vi a abertura da tag "dependencies".

Comment: opa, obrigado pelo feedback, o pom está com a tag dependencies aberta aqui sim, só nao saiu no código ai, tentei desse jeito e também nao deu, resolvi o problema indo no site oficial do spring.io, e criando um projeto com Web + JPA +WebServices + Spring Data, o site criou pra mim e funcionou aqui, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

Fui no site spring.io e criei um projeto com as seguintes configurações:
-Web
-Web Services
-JPA
-Spring data.

funcionou sem problemas.
valeu galera.